# Calendar program prints days of the week vertically need horizontal

Tags: python

I've been working on this calendar code. I've run into an issue, i'm unable to figure out where or why the code is printing the days of the week down the page rather than where they normally would be.
I took out a lot of the space that was given with the output.

```
def getCalendar(month, day):
    DaysOfWeek = ['sunday','monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday']
    DaysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    date = 1

    for i in DaysOfWeek:
        # Prints the days of the week with 1 letter for month header
        print(i[0:1].upper(), end='\t')
        # accepts input of day as lowercase
        if day.lower() in DaysOfWeek:
            for i in range(6):
                for j in range(7):
                    if j >= DaysOfWeek.index(day.lower()) and date <= DaysInMonth[month - 1]:
                        print(date, end='\t')
                        date += 1
                    else:
                        print(end='\t')
                # start of the week
                day = 'sunday'
                print()
        else:
            print('Invalid weekday entered!')


def main():
    months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
              'August','September','August','November','December']

    month = int(input('Enter the month number:'))
    week = input('Enter weekday: ')

    print('\n\t\t' + months[month - 1])
    getCalendar(month, week)


main()
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter the month number:5
Enter weekday: monday

        May
S       1   2   3   4   5   6   
7   8   9   10  11  12  13  
14  15  16  17  18  19  20  
21  22  23  24  25  26  27  
28  29  30  31              
                            
M                                           
T                                       
W                                       
T
F                       
S
```

Answer (score 0):

Revised in response to comments. The name of the day of the week after the month name is converted to a single line and created for later looping process.
My question is, what is the requirement to enter the day of the week? If it's a starting day of the week, you need to fix the logic.

```
def getCalendar(month, day):
    DaysOfWeek = ['sunday','monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday']
    DaysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    date = 1

#     for i in DaysOfWeek:
    # Prints the days of the week with 1 letter for month header
    # print(i[0:1].upper(), end='\t')
    week = [w[0:1].upper() for w in DaysOfWeek]
    print('\t'.join(week))
    # accepts input of day as lowercase
    if day.lower() in DaysOfWeek:
        for i in range(6):
            for j in range(7):
                if j >= DaysOfWeek.index(day.lower()) and date <= DaysInMonth[month - 1]:
                    print(date, end='\t')
                    date += 1
                else:
                    print(end='\t')
            # start of the week
            day = 'sunday'
            print()
    else:
        print('Invalid weekday entered!')


def main():
    months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
              'August','September','August','November','December']

    month = int(input('Enter the month number:'))
    week = input('Enter weekday: ')

    print('\n\t\t' + months[month - 1])
    getCalendar(month, week)


main()

        May
S   M   T   W   T   F   S
    1   2   3   4   5   6   
7   8   9   10  11  12  13  
14  15  16  17  18  19  20  
21  22  23  24  25  26  27  
28  29  30  31
```

Comment: Yes I am aware. But for the current assignment I must do it another way and create my own. I just need to know why the days of the week aren't displaying properly